# save subplots after .imshow()

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, subplot, savefig

Here are my visualization codes:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
for i, img in enumerate([img1, img2]):    
    grads = # my visualization codes
# visualize grads as heatmap
ax[i].imshow(grads, cmap='jet')
```

How could I save whatever was shown using `imshow` here? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to save the whole figure (all subplots), or save each subplot to a separate file?

Comment: @mostlyoxygen preferably both? But either way is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving the whole figure is simple, just use the `savefig` function:

```
f.savefig('filename.png')
```

There are a number of file formats you can save to, and these are usually inferred correctly from the extension of the filename.  See [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.savefig) for more information.

The `savefig` function takes an argument `bbox_inches`, which defines the area of the figure to be saved.  To save an individual subplot to file you can use the bounding box of the subplot's `Axes` object to calculate the appropriate value.

Putting it all together your code would look something like this:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
for i, img in enumerate([img1, img2]):    
    grads = # my visualization codes
    # visualize grads as heatmap
    ax[i].imshow(grads, cmap='jet')

    # Save the subplot.
    bbox = ax[i].get_tightbbox(f.canvas.get_renderer())
    f.savefig("subplot{}.png".format(i),
              bbox_inches=bbox.transformed(f.dpi_scale_trans.inverted()))

# Save the whole figure.
f.savefig("whole_figure.png")
```

Comment: This answer works, but in my case all the labels, legends, etc are shifted so that they overlap in the saved images. They do that also in the `show`n plot, unless I maximize the window. Using [fig.set_size_inches(16,9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041627/how-to-make-pylab-savefig-save-image-for-maximized-window-instead-of-default) and the optional argument in `savefig` `dpi=300` fixed that for me.